# Gradle jettyRun: how does this thing work?

Tags: testing, selenium, jetty, gradle

Normally, I would start Jetty by constructing a Server instance, setting a connector, a handler, and `LifeCycleListener`, followed by a call to `start()` on the Server instance.  I haven't the foggiest idea how to make this happen with the `jettyRun` task in Gradle.  The documentation is confusing to me, and I have yet to find an example of how this task works, other than page after page of `gradle jettyRun`.

This task is appealing to me because it allegedly returns immediately after execution.  This is helpful for running Selenium tests after my webapp is running from Jenkins.  I tried to do this via a `JavaExec` task, but this won't work since the `JavaExec` task does not terminate until the underlying JVM terminates as well.

Comment: If you want to know about the internals, why don't you study the [source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/jetty/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/jetty)?

Comment: You can always check yourself - [`org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun`](http://svn.codehaus.org/gradle/gradle-core/tags/REL-0.7/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/jetty/JettyRun.java)

Comment: Check my answer here, using the ant Jetty task http://stackoverflow.com/a/18021790/39334

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to start Jetty for in-container integration tests. Besides having a look at the source code these two posts should get you started:

- [War and Jetty plugins with http integration tests](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRADLE/War+and+Jetty+plugins+with+http+integration+tests)
- [Right way to do basic web integration testing?](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Right-way-to-do-basic-web-integration-testing-td2837065.html)

The key feature you are looking for, starting Jetty in the background, is `jettyRun.daemon = true`.

Comment: Ugh, looks like this requires I mess with a bunch of messy XML.  I prefer the short java-based launcher I currently use.  The Jetty plugin is only convenient for super-simple setups it seems.

Answer (score 2):

What I'm using for integration test in `build.gradle` is looks like below. I think this code is simple and intuitive.

```
test {
    exclude '**/*IntegrationTest*'
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    include '**/*IntegrationTest*'
    doFirst {
        jettyRun.httpPort = 8080    // Port for test
        jettyRun.daemon = true
        jettyRun.execute()
    }
    doLast {
        jettyStop.stopPort = 8091   // Port for stop signal
        jettyStop.stopKey = 'stopKey'
        jettyStop.execute()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble using this code, it seems like jettyStop does not work, as after task is completed, jetty is still running, any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: I've tried it with different ports, either i've been unlucky, or there's something more to it. Either way, i'll have a look